# How to efficiently find the first timestamp of each day/week/month in an array of timestamps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-series, timestamp

I have a long array of sorted timestamps (stock price quotes). The timestamps have a minimal resolution (e.g. each TS is at least 1 minute bigger than the previous one), but there can be gaps during the day (especially in the pre/after hour sessions) and there is no data for weekends and holidays.
I want to (efficiently) find the timestamps that start a new interval (e.g. day, week or month - depending on the time range) for charting purposes.

My current solution is looping through the array and creating a Date from each timestamp, then comparing the .getDay() of the previous and current array element.

```
let rangeSecs = data[data.length-1]- data[0];
let rangeDays = rangeSecs / 86400;  //data has timestamps in seconds, not ms.
let spt=[]; //array of indexes of the "timestamps of interest"
const minInterval=data.slice(0,9).reduce((ac,x,i,ar)=>Math.min(ac,x-ar[i-1]))

let prevdate=new Date(data[0]*1000)

for(let i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    const curDate=new Date(data[i]*1000)
    if(rangeDays>70 && prevdate.getMonth()!=curDate.getMonth() ){  //monthly
        spt.push(i)
    }else if(rangeDays<=70 && rangeDays>14 && prevdate.getDay()>curDate.getDay() ){ //weekly
        spt.push(i)
                                
    }else if(rangeDays<=14 && prevdate.getDay()!=curDate.getDay() ){  //daily
        spt.push(i)
    }
    prevdate=curDate;

}
```

It works but it is quite slow.
Has anyone an idea how to speed it up?

I tried skipping some "safe" amount of timestamps, but because I can't know for sure how many datapoints there will be per day (except for the regular trading hours), the optimization is not optimal/generic.

EDIT: Sample data as per request. It covers ca. one month, with minimal timestamp interval of 15 minutes.

```
[1625572800,1625573700,1625574600,1625576400,1625578200,1625579100,1625580000,1625580900,1625581800,1625582700,1625583600,1625584500,1625585400,1625586300,1625587200,1625588100,1625589000,1625589900,1625590800,1625591700,1625592600,1625593500,1625594400,1625595300,1625596200,1625597100,1625598000,1625598900,1625599800,1625600700,1625601600,1625602500,1625603400,1625604300,1625605200,1625606100,1625607000,1625607900,1625609700,1625613300,1625615100,1625656500,1625659200,1625660100,1625664600,1625665500,1625666400,1625667300,1625668200,1625669100,1625670000,1625670900,1625671800,1625672700,1625673600,1625674500,1625675400,1625676300,1625677200,1625678100,1625679000,1625679900,1625680800,1625681700,1625682600,1625683500,1625684400,1625685300,1625686200,1625687100,1625688000,1625690700,1625691600,1625693400,1625694300,1625695200,1625697900,1625700600,1625743800,1625745600,1625746500,1625747400,1625748300,1625749200,1625751000,1625751900,1625752800,1625753700,1625754600,1625755500,1625756400,1625757300,1625758200,1625759100,1625760000,1625760900,1625761800,1625762700,1625763600,1625764500,1625765400,1625766300,1625767200,1625768100,1625769000,1625769900,1625770800,1625771700,1625772600,1625773500,1625774400,1625784300,1625786100,1625787000,1625830200,1625832000,1625832900,1625834700,1625837400,1625838300,1625839200,1625840100,1625841000,1625841900,1625842800,1625843700,1625844600,1625845500,1625846400,1625847300,1625848200,1625849100,1625850000,1625850900,1625851800,1625852700,1625853600,1625854500,1625855400,1625856300,1625857200,1625858100,1625859000,1625859900,1625860800,1625862600,1625867100,1625871600,1626087600,1626091200,1626096600,1626097500,1626098400,1626099300,1626100200,1626101100,1626102000,1626102900,1626103800,1626104700,1626105600,1626106500,1626107400,1626108300,1626109200,1626110100,1626111000,1626111900,1626112800,1626113700,1626114600,1626115500,1626116400,1626117300,1626118200,1626119100,1626120000,1626123600,1626129900,1626178500,1626183000,1626183900,1626184800,1626185700,1626186600,1626187500,1626188400,1626189300,1626190200,1626191100,1626192000,1626192900,1626193800,1626194700,1626195600,1626196500,1626197400,1626198300,1626199200,1626200100,1626201000,1626201900,1626202800,1626203700,1626204600,1626205500,1626206400,1626213600,1626215400,1626262200,1626264000,1626267600,1626269400,1626270300,1626271200,1626272100,1626273000,1626273900,1626274800,1626275700,1626276600,1626277500,1626278400,1626279300,1626280200,1626281100,1626282000,1626282900,1626283800,1626284700,1626285600,1626286500,1626287400,1626288300,1626289200,1626290100,1626291000,1626291900,1626292800,1626293700,1626295500,1626300000,1626302700,1626306300,1626342300,1626346800,1626349500,1626350400,1626351300,1626352200,1626353100,1626355800,1626356700,1626357600,1626358500,1626359400,1626360300,1626361200,1626362100,1626363000,1626363900,1626364800,1626365700,1626366600,1626367500,1626368400,1626369300,1626370200,1626371100,1626372000,1626372900,1626373800,1626374700,1626375600,1626376500,1626377400,1626378300,1626379200,1626381000,1626381900,1626386400,1626390900,1626433200,1626438600,1626442200,1626443100,1626444000,1626444900,1626445800,1626446700,1626447600,1626448500,1626449400,1626450300,1626451200,1626452100,1626453000,1626453900,1626454800,1626455700,1626456600,1626457500,1626458400,1626459300,1626460200,1626461100,1626462000,1626462900,1626463800,1626464700,1626465600,1626466500,1626477300,1626692400,1626696000,1626696900,1626697800,1626698700,1626699600,1626701400,1626702300,1626703200,1626704100,1626705000,1626705900,1626706800,1626707700,1626708600,1626709500,1626710400,1626711300,1626712200,1626713100,1626714000,1626714900,1626715800,1626716700,1626717600,1626718500,1626719400,1626720300,1626721200,1626722100,1626723000,1626723900,1626724800,1626725700,1626727500,1626731100,1626735600,1626737400,1626778800,1626780600,1626783300,1626784200,1626785100,1626787800,1626788700,1626789600,1626790500,1626791400,1626792300,1626793200,1626794100,1626795000,1626795900,1626796800,1626797700,1626798600,1626799500,1626800400,1626801300,1626802200,1626803100,1626804000,1626804900,1626805800,1626806700,1626807600,1626808500,1626809400,1626810300,1626811200,1626869700,1626872400,1626874200,1626875100,1626876000,1626876900,1626877800,1626878700,1626879600,1626880500,1626881400,1626882300,1626883200,1626884100,1626885000,1626885900,1626886800,1626887700,1626888600,1626889500,1626890400,1626891300,1626892200,1626893100,1626894000,1626894900,1626895800,1626896700,1626897600,1626955200,1626957000,1626960600,1626961500,1626962400,1626963300,1626964200,1626965100,1626966000,1626966900,1626967800,1626968700,1626969600,1626970500,1626971400,1626972300,1626973200,1626974100,1626975000,1626975900,1626976800,1626977700,1626978600,1626979500,1626980400,1626981300,1626982200,1626983100,1626984000,1626992100,1627047000,1627047900,1627048800,1627049700,1627050600,1627051500,1627052400,1627053300,1627054200,1627055100,1627056000,1627056900,1627057800,1627058700,1627059600,1627060500,1627061400,1627062300,1627063200,1627064100,1627065000,1627065900,1627066800,1627067700,1627068600,1627069500,1627070400,1627074900,1627300800,1627306200,1627307100,1627308000,1627308900,1627309800,1627310700,1627311600,1627312500,1627313400,1627314300,1627315200,1627316100,1627317000,1627317900,1627318800,1627319700,1627320600,1627321500,1627322400,1627323300,1627324200,1627325100,1627326000,1627326900,1627327800,1627328700,1627329600,1627387200,1627388100,1627392600,1627393500,1627394400,1627395300,1627396200,1627397100,1627398000,1627398900,1627399800,1627400700,1627401600,1627402500,1627403400,1627404300,1627405200,1627406100,1627407000,1627407900,1627408800,1627409700,1627410600,1627411500,1627412400,1627413300,1627414200,1627415100,1627416000,1627479000,1627479900,1627480800,1627481700,1627482600,1627483500,1627484400,1627485300,1627486200,1627487100,1627488000,1627488900,1627489800,1627490700,1627491600,1627492500,1627493400,1627494300,1627495200,1627496100,1627497000,1627497900,1627498800,1627499700,1627500600,1627501500,1627502400,1627565400,1627566300,1627567200,1627568100,1627569000,1627569900,1627570800,1627571700,1627572600,1627573500,1627574400,1627575300,1627576200,1627577100,1627578000,1627578900,1627579800,1627580700,1627581600,1627582500,1627583400,1627584300,1627585200,1627586100,1627587000,1627587900,1627588800,1627599600,1627600500,1627646400,1627651800,1627652700,1627653600,1627654500,1627655400,1627656300,1627657200,1627658100,1627659000,1627659900,1627660800,1627661700,1627662600,1627663500,1627664400,1627665300,1627666200,1627667100,1627668000,1627668900,1627669800,1627670700,1627671600,1627672500,1627673400,1627674300,1627675200,1627676100]
```

Comment: Are the timestamps in the array numbers or strings? An example of the array with, say, 10-15 entries would be very useful in terms of helping people help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just numbers, here's an example: [1625578200, 1625578500, 1625578800, 1625579100, 1625579400, 1625579700, 1625580000, 1625580300, 1625580600, 1625580900]

Comment: I doubt it's the problem, but the comment *"data has timestamps in seconds, not ms."* suggests that `new Date(data[0])` and similar are incorrect. It should be `new Date(data[0] * 1000)`. The `Date` constructor, when given a number, interprets it as *milliseconds* since The Epoch.

Comment: What are `scaleMin` and `scaleMax`?

Comment: Those sample data values cover a grand total of 45 minutes, which is shorter than even your most minimal interval. Please edit the question with **representative** sample data (for instance, perhaps three sets of 20 entries, one per desired interval [monthly, weekly, daily]).

Comment: Your exaple values are also in ascending order, but `let rangeSecs = data[0] - data[data.length-1];` suggests the data is in descending order...? (Otherwise, that's always a negative number.)

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry, I adjusted the example code since the real one had some unnecessary complexity (array of arrays) and chart-framework specifics. In my real code it is the other way around. I corrected the sample code again.

Comment: It would probably be easier to come at it from the other end.  Generate an array of the timestamps x for each period on your chart, then use array.findIndex(n=>n>x) on your data to find the indexes in your data that are greater than each x in your chart gradations, then take the array of indexes and intersect to get a trimmed out array of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to convert every timestamp to a `Date` object. Instead, when you have an interesting date, figure out the timestamp value for the next interesting date (the current one plus a month, a week, or a day) and skip over the subsequent timestamps that are less than that value. (See also various comments on the question.)

I've made a couple of assumptions in the code below that you can adjust as appropriate — for instance, that the next minimum timestamp should always start on a Monday if the interval is a week, and that it should always start a midnight (regardless of day, week, or month).

See comments:

```
// Function to find the indexes of the interesting dates in the given data
function findIndexes(data) {
    let rangeSecs = data[data.length-1] - data[0];
    let rangeDays = rangeSecs / 86400;  // data has timestamps in seconds, not ms.
    let spt = []; // array of indexes of the "timestamps of interest"

    // You didn't say what these were, so I'm just using the whole array
    const scaleMin = 0;
    const scaleMax = data.length - 1;

    // Figure out what kind of interval we want: month, week, or day
    const interval = rangeDays > 70 ? "month" : rangeDays <= 14 ? "day" : "week";
    /*
    console.log(`${displayString(data[0])} to ${displayString(data[data.length-1])}, rangeDays = ${rangeDays}, interval = ${interval}`);
    */
    // First date is presumably always of interest (but you could remove this if not)
    spt.push(scaleMin);
    // Remember the last "interesting" date
    let prevdate = new Date(data[0] * 1000);
    // Find the timestamp value for the next interesting date
    let minNext = getMinNext(interval, prevdate);
    // Loop through the data
    for (let i = scaleMin + 1; i <= scaleMax; ++i) {
        const value = data[i];
        // Is this value at or above the next minimum value?
        if (value >= minNext) {
            // Yes, it's "interesting" -- save it and get the next one
            spt.push(i);
            prevdate = new Date(value * 1000);
            minNext = getMinNext(interval, prevdate);
        }
    }

    return spt;
}

// Subroutine of `findIndexes`
function getMinNext(interval, prevdate) {
    let nextTime;
    if (interval === "month") {
        // Find out when the next month starts by adding a month and clearing the hours,
        // minutes, seconds, and milliseconds
        nextTime = new Date(+prevdate);
        nextTime.setMonth(nextTime.getMonth() + 1);
        nextTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        // Find out when the next week or day starts
        const intervalLength = interval === "day" ? 86400 : 7 * 86400;
        nextTime = new Date(+prevdate + (intervalLength * 1000));
        nextTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (interval === "week") {
            // Going by weeks, scan backward to Monday (this only scans the first time,
            // after that we add seven days so it's always Monday)
            while (nextTime.getDay() !== 1) {
                nextTime.setDate(nextTime.getDate() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    const minNext = Math.floor(nextTime / 1000);
    /*
    console.log(`minNext for ${displayString(prevdate)} is ${displayString(minNext)}`);
    */
    return minNext;
}
```

Live Example with random data:

```js
// Function to find the indexes of the interesting dates in the given data
function findIndexes(data) {
    let rangeSecs = data[data.length-1] - data[0];
    let rangeDays = rangeSecs / 86400;  // data has timestamps in seconds, not ms.
    let spt = []; // array of indexes of the "timestamps of interest"

    // You didn't say what these were, so I'm just using the whole array
    const scaleMin = 0;
    const scaleMax = data.length - 1;

    // Figure out what kind of interval we want: month, week, or day
    const interval = rangeDays > 70 ? "month" : rangeDays <= 14 ? "day" : "week";
    /*
    console.log(`${displayString(data[0])} to ${displayString(data[data.length-1])}, rangeDays = ${rangeDays}, interval = ${interval}`);
    */
    // First date is presumably always of interest (but you could remove this if not)
    spt.push(scaleMin);
    // Remember the last "interesting" date
    let prevdate = new Date(data[0] * 1000);
    // Find the timestamp value for the next interesting date
    let minNext = getMinNext(interval, prevdate);
    // Loop through the data
    for (let i = scaleMin + 1; i <= scaleMax; ++i) {
        const value = data[i];
        // Is this value at or above the next minimum value?
        if (value >= minNext) {
            // Yes, it's "interesting" -- save it and get the next one
            spt.push(i);
            prevdate = new Date(value * 1000);
            minNext = getMinNext(interval, prevdate);
        }
    }

    return spt;
}

// Subroutine of `findIndexes`
function getMinNext(interval, prevdate) {
    let nextTime;
    if (interval === "month") {
        // Find out when the next month starts by going back to the 1st, adding a month and clearing the hours,
        // minutes, seconds, and milliseconds
        nextTime = new Date(+prevdate);
        nextTime.setDate(1);
        nextTime.setMonth(nextTime.getMonth() + 1);
        nextTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        // Find out when the next week or day starts
        const intervalLength = interval === "day" ? 86400 : 7 * 86400;
        nextTime = new Date(+prevdate + (intervalLength * 1000));
        nextTime.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        if (interval === "week") {
            // Going by weeks, scan backward to Monday (this only scans the first time,
            // after that we add seven days so it's always Monday)
            while (nextTime.getDay() !== 1) {
                nextTime.setDate(nextTime.getDate() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    const minNext = Math.floor(nextTime / 1000);
    /*
    console.log(`minNext for ${displayString(prevdate)} is ${displayString(minNext)}`);
    */
    return minNext;
}

// Examples:
let indexes;
console.log("Days:");
const daysData = getRandomData(3 * 60 * 60); // Up to 4 hour intervals
indexes = findIndexes(daysData);
console.log(indexes.map(index => new Date(daysData[index] * 1000).toLocaleString()));
console.log("Weeks:");
const weeksData = getRandomData(3 * 24 * 60 * 60); // Up to 3 day intervals
indexes = findIndexes(weeksData);
console.log(indexes.map(index => new Date(weeksData[index] * 1000).toLocaleString()));
console.log("Months:");
const monthsData = getRandomData(21 * 24 * 60 * 60); // Up to 3 week intervals
indexes = findIndexes(monthsData);
console.log(indexes.map(index => new Date(monthsData[index] * 1000).toLocaleString()));
console.log("Your sample data:");
const sampleData = getSampleData();
indexes = findIndexes(sampleData);
console.log(indexes.map(index => new Date(sampleData[index] * 1000).toLocaleString()));

// Make random data for us
function getRandomData(interval) {
    let value = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const data = Array.from({length: 20}, () => {
        const current = value;
        value += Math.floor(Math.random() * interval);
        return current;
    });
    /*
    for (const value of data) {
        console.log(new Date(value * 1000).toLocaleString());
    }
    */
    return data;
}

function displayString(value) {
    if (typeof value === "number") {
        value = new Date(value * 1000);
    }
    return value.toLocaleString();
}

function getSampleData() {
    return [
        1625572800,1625573700,1625574600,1625576400,1625578200,1625579100,1625580000,1625580900,
        1625581800,1625582700,1625583600,1625584500,1625585400,1625586300,
        1625587200,1625588100,1625589000,1625589900,1625590800,1625591700,
        1625592600,1625593500,1625594400,1625595300,1625596200,1625597100,
        1625598000,1625598900,1625599800,1625600700,1625601600,1625602500,
        1625603400,1625604300,1625605200,1625606100,1625607000,1625607900,
        1625609700,1625613300,1625615100,1625656500,1625659200,1625660100,
        1625664600,1625665500,1625666400,1625667300,1625668200,1625669100,
        1625670000,1625670900,1625671800,1625672700,1625673600,1625674500,
        1625675400,1625676300,1625677200,1625678100,1625679000,1625679900,
        1625680800,1625681700,1625682600,1625683500,1625684400,1625685300,
        1625686200,1625687100,1625688000,1625690700,1625691600,1625693400,
        1625694300,1625695200,1625697900,1625700600,1625743800,1625745600,
        1625746500,1625747400,1625748300,1625749200,1625751000,1625751900,
        1625752800,1625753700,1625754600,1625755500,1625756400,1625757300,
        1625758200,1625759100,1625760000,1625760900,1625761800,1625762700,
        1625763600,1625764500,1625765400,1625766300,1625767200,1625768100,
        1625769000,1625769900,1625770800,1625771700,1625772600,1625773500,
        1625774400,1625784300,1625786100,1625787000,1625830200,1625832000,
        1625832900,1625834700,1625837400,1625838300,1625839200,1625840100,
        1625841000,1625841900,1625842800,1625843700,1625844600,1625845500,
        1625846400,1625847300,1625848200,1625849100,1625850000,1625850900,
        1625851800,1625852700,1625853600,1625854500,1625855400,1625856300,
        1625857200,1625858100,1625859000,1625859900,1625860800,1625862600,
        1625867100,1625871600,1626087600,1626091200,1626096600,1626097500,
        1626098400,1626099300,1626100200,1626101100,1626102000,1626102900,
        1626103800,1626104700,1626105600,1626106500,1626107400,1626108300,
        1626109200,1626110100,1626111000,1626111900,1626112800,1626113700,
        1626114600,1626115500,1626116400,1626117300,1626118200,1626119100,
        1626120000,1626123600,1626129900,1626178500,1626183000,1626183900,
        1626184800,1626185700,1626186600,1626187500,1626188400,1626189300,
        1626190200,1626191100,1626192000,1626192900,1626193800,1626194700,
        1626195600,1626196500,1626197400,1626198300,1626199200,1626200100,
        1626201000,1626201900,1626202800,1626203700,1626204600,1626205500,
        1626206400,1626213600,1626215400,1626262200,1626264000,1626267600,
        1626269400,1626270300,1626271200,1626272100,1626273000,1626273900,
        1626274800,1626275700,1626276600,1626277500,1626278400,1626279300,
        1626280200,1626281100,1626282000,1626282900,1626283800,1626284700,
        1626285600,1626286500,1626287400,1626288300,1626289200,1626290100,
        1626291000,1626291900,1626292800,1626293700,1626295500,1626300000,
        1626302700,1626306300,1626342300,1626346800,1626349500,1626350400,
        1626351300,1626352200,1626353100,1626355800,1626356700,1626357600,
        1626358500,1626359400,1626360300,1626361200,1626362100,1626363000,
        1626363900,1626364800,1626365700,1626366600,1626367500,1626368400,
        1626369300,1626370200,1626371100,1626372000,1626372900,1626373800,
        1626374700,1626375600,1626376500,1626377400,1626378300,1626379200,
        1626381000,1626381900,1626386400,1626390900,1626433200,1626438600,
        1626442200,1626443100,1626444000,1626444900,1626445800,1626446700,
        1626447600,1626448500,1626449400,1626450300,1626451200,1626452100,
        1626453000,1626453900,1626454800,1626455700,1626456600,1626457500,
        1626458400,1626459300,1626460200,1626461100,1626462000,1626462900,
        1626463800,1626464700,1626465600,1626466500,1626477300,1626692400,
        1626696000,1626696900,1626697800,1626698700,1626699600,1626701400,
        1626702300,1626703200,1626704100,1626705000,1626705900,1626706800,
        1626707700,1626708600,1626709500,1626710400,1626711300,1626712200,
        1626713100,1626714000,1626714900,1626715800,1626716700,1626717600,
        1626718500,1626719400,1626720300,1626721200,1626722100,1626723000,
        1626723900,1626724800,1626725700,1626727500,1626731100,1626735600,
        1626737400,1626778800,1626780600,1626783300,1626784200,1626785100,
        1626787800,1626788700,1626789600,1626790500,1626791400,1626792300,
        1626793200,1626794100,1626795000,1626795900,1626796800,1626797700,
        1626798600,1626799500,1626800400,1626801300,1626802200,1626803100,
        1626804000,1626804900,1626805800,1626806700,1626807600,1626808500,
        1626809400,1626810300,1626811200,1626869700,1626872400,1626874200,
        1626875100,1626876000,1626876900,1626877800,1626878700,1626879600,
        1626880500,1626881400,1626882300,1626883200,1626884100,1626885000,
        1626885900,1626886800,1626887700,1626888600,1626889500,1626890400,
        1626891300,1626892200,1626893100,1626894000,1626894900,1626895800,
        1626896700,1626897600,1626955200,1626957000,1626960600,1626961500,
        1626962400,1626963300,1626964200,1626965100,1626966000,1626966900,
        1626967800,1626968700,1626969600,1626970500,1626971400,1626972300,
        1626973200,1626974100,1626975000,1626975900,1626976800,1626977700,
        1626978600,1626979500,1626980400,1626981300,1626982200,1626983100,
        1626984000,1626992100,1627047000,1627047900,1627048800,1627049700,
        1627050600,1627051500,1627052400,1627053300,1627054200,1627055100,
        1627056000,1627056900,1627057800,1627058700,1627059600,1627060500,
        1627061400,1627062300,1627063200,1627064100,1627065000,1627065900,
        1627066800,1627067700,1627068600,1627069500,1627070400,1627074900,
        1627300800,1627306200,1627307100,1627308000,1627308900,1627309800,
        1627310700,1627311600,1627312500,1627313400,1627314300,1627315200,
        1627316100,1627317000,1627317900,1627318800,1627319700,1627320600,
        1627321500,1627322400,1627323300,1627324200,1627325100,1627326000,
        1627326900,1627327800,1627328700,1627329600,1627387200,1627388100,
        1627392600,1627393500,1627394400,1627395300,1627396200,1627397100,
        1627398000,1627398900,1627399800,1627400700,1627401600,1627402500,
        1627403400,1627404300,1627405200,1627406100,1627407000,1627407900,
        1627408800,1627409700,1627410600,1627411500,1627412400,1627413300,
        1627414200,1627415100,1627416000,1627479000,1627479900,1627480800,
        1627481700,1627482600,1627483500,1627484400,1627485300,1627486200,
        1627487100,1627488000,1627488900,1627489800,1627490700,1627491600,
        1627492500,1627493400,1627494300,1627495200,1627496100,1627497000,
        1627497900,1627498800,1627499700,1627500600,1627501500,1627502400,
        1627565400,1627566300,1627567200,1627568100,1627569000,1627569900,
        1627570800,1627571700,1627572600,1627573500,1627574400,1627575300,
        1627576200,1627577100,1627578000,1627578900,1627579800,1627580700,
        1627581600,1627582500,1627583400,1627584300,1627585200,1627586100,
        1627587000,1627587900,1627588800,1627599600,1627600500,1627646400,
        1627651800,1627652700,1627653600,1627654500,1627655400,1627656300,
        1627657200,1627658100,1627659000,1627659900,1627660800,1627661700,
        1627662600,1627663500,1627664400,1627665300,1627666200,1627667100,
        1627668000,1627668900,1627669800,1627670700,1627671600,1627672500,
        1627673400,1627674300,1627675200,1627676100
];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: While I was initially sceptical about the performance improvement, since you still loop through the whole array, the result is actually EXTREMELY fast. It reduced the execution time from around 500ms to below 1ms!

I had to add a nextTime.setUTCDate(1); to the getMinNext() for calculating the next "month" . Without it, the returned month intervals were starting later and later.

Comment: @tommyleejones - Oops! I missed that one out -- and it's important that it be *before* the `setMonth`. But since all the rest of it is in local time, that should be `setDate`, not `setUTCDate` (or change all of them to UTC if you want UTC). Yeah, the performance improvement comes from avoiding most of the object creation calls and most of the date/time calculations done within the `Date` class for `getDate`, etc. Glad that helped! :-)